# Proving that all generators of a cyclic group $G = <a>$, are of the form $a^k$, where $(k,n := o(G)) = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is my attempt :

Suppose $a^k$ is a generator of $G$ with $(k,n) = d > 1$, so we have $n = md$ and $k = rd$, for some integers $m$ and $r$ such that $1 < m < n$ and $1 \leq r < n$ (since $k < n$ and $d > 1$).

Then, the cyclic group generated by $a^k$ is :
$$ \{a^k, a^{2k}, \cdots, a^{nk} = e\} $$, which is nothing but :
$$ \{a^{rd},a^{2rd}, \cdots, a^{nrd} = e\}$$, where we assume that all the $n$ elements are distinct (we are assuming $a^k$ is a generator of $G$).
But, $a^{mrd} = (a^{md})^r = (a^n)^r = e^r = e$ and $m < n$, contradicting the assumption that the elements are distinct. So, we are only left with checking the case $(k,n) = 1$.

Let $(k,n) = 1$, and let $o(a^k) = m$ (sorry for the abuse of notation). Then, $m \mid n$. Suppose $n \nmid mk$. Then, $mk = r_0 n + r_1$, with $1 \leq r_1 < n$, and so, $a^{mk} = (a^n)^{r_0} \cdot a^{r_1} = e$, and that implies $a^{r_1} = e$ with $r_1 < n$, which contradicts $G = <a>$. Therefore, $n \mid mk$ and $(n,k) = 1$. This implies that $n \mid m$.

Since $m \mid n$ and $n \mid m$ and both $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers, we have $m = n$, i.e., $a^k$ is a generator of $G$. This completes the proof $\blacksquare$

Is my proof correct? Is there another way to prove this theorem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to see it, which requires only a bit of elementary number theory: If $G=\left \langle  a\right \rangle$ where $o(a)=n$, then for all $k$, $$o(a^{k})=\frac{n}{(n,k)}.$$ First, I write $d:=(n,k)$ and $m:=o(a^{k})$ to make the notation a little less cumbersome. Next, note that $(a^{k})^{\frac{n}{d}}=(a^{n})^{\frac{k}{d}}=e^{\frac{k}{d}}=e$, so $m | \frac{n}{d}$. Similarly, $(a^{k})^{m}=a^{km}=e$, so $n|km$, which implies $\frac{n}{d}|m\frac{k}{d}$. Now, $d=(n,k)$, so $(\frac{n}{d},\frac{k}{d})=1$; so the only way $\frac{n}{d}$ can divide $m\frac{k}{d}$ is if $\frac{n}{d}|m$, by Euclid's Lemma, so we're done. Can you use this to prove your claim?

Comment: Wow that's an elegant solution! Thanks for writing it out so clearly. This way, there's no need to write out "if" and "only if" proofs as, from the expression $o(a^{k})=\frac{n}{(n,k)}$, it is clear that $o(a^{k}) = n \iff (n,k) = 1$. I will use this thought process in future problems now!

Comment: Yep, you got it! No problem at all by the way!